# TypeError: Reflect.getOwnMetadata is not a function

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, typescript, angular

I am trying to setup angular2 rc4 with ASPNET 5 in Visual Studio 2015. At the moment I am having this error and I am not sure what the problem is. I've been having quite a lot of pain trying to get this running properly.

Here is my systemjs.config.js

```
(function (global) {
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    var map = {
        'app': 'app', // 'dist',
        '@angular': 'js/@angular',
        'ng2-dnd': 'js/ng2-dnd',
        'rxjs': 'js/rxjs',
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'js/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    };

    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    var packages = {
        'app': { main: 'main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        '@angular': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'ng2-dnd': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    };


    var packageNames = [
      'common',
      'compiler',
      'core', // <--------
      'http',
      'platform-browser',
      'platform-browser-dynamic',
      'router',
      'router-deprecated',
      'testing',
      'upgrade',
    ];

    // Individual files (~300 requests):
    function packIndex(pkgName) {
        packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    }

    // Bundled (~40 requests):
    function packUmd(pkgName) {
        packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = { main: 'bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    }

    // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
    var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;

    packageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);

    var config = {
        map: map,
        packages: packages
    }

    System.config(config);

})(this);
```

[image]

Comment: Compare your `index.html` with https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/index.html `zone` and `reflect` are reguired

Comment: Oh god, thanks. That worked. If you make an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: The above link is dead, this is the correct one: https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/src/index.html